# Magento 1.7 Installation Error in DreamHost shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, magento, apache2, magento-1.7

Error in the Logs is

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://www.example.com/index.php/install/wizard/config/?config%5Blocale%5D=en_US&config%5Btimezone%5D=America%2FLos_Angeles&config%5Bcurrency%5D=USD
```

Error shown in magento installation screen

```
Error log record number: 425991650051
```

Also i found that during installation only 86 tables were sucessfully added in the magento database.

phpinfo of the Server

```
display_errors  On
max_execution_time  30
memory_limit    90M
safe_mode   Off
cURL support    enabled 
PDO support enabled
Simplexml support   enabled
mcrypt support  enabled
hash support    enabled
GD Support  enabled
DOM/XML     enabled 
iconv support   enabled 
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled 

Mysql Server version: 5.1.56
PHP Version 5.3.13
```

Changes made in index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Initially i thought it was due to memory_limit and max_execution_time, but i recreated this same scenario in my localhost and it worked sucessfully inspite of memory being limited to 90M and max exec time as 30

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

change the permissions on index.php to 644.

also changed the directories permission: app, var, media and app/etc to 755

Comment: yes i have done that, and how does that affect the script to end prematurely

Comment: can you open the /var/report/425991650051

and post the content here..
not sure why but i've been experiencing this on my localhost, after i changed the permission, it works well

but it could be different problem :D